# Send logged in user details to admin on button click using phpmailer

Tags: php, pdo

I cant seem to find a solution to this on the site. What I would like to do is to have the user click on a button. This will then send a mail to me or someone in the office and the mail would then contain the logged in user details. I am sending the mail successfully, but I am unsure on how to get the code to send me the users info. Here is my code:

```
include 'contact/config.php';

require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE UCODE=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{

$name = $row['firstname'];
$email = $row['billingemail'];
$subject = "myDraadloze Package Contact Card";
$message = stripslashes($_POST['Please contact user regarding example']);


$error = '';



if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message, 
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}


}
?>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest reading the PHP docs, and using PHPMailer, that you tagged this question with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include 'contact/config.php';

  require_once 'class.user.php';
  $user_home = new USER();

 if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
 {
$user_home->redirect('index.php');
  }
 else
{
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE UCODE=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
   $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

  $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

 if($post)
   {

$name = $row['firstname'];
  $email = $row['billingemail'];
   $subject = "myDraadloze Package Contact Card";
$email_to = " email@gmail.com";


 $message = .= "Firstname: ".($name)."\n\n";
    $message = .= "Email: ".($email)."\n\n";
    $message = .= "Firstname: ".($name)."\n\n";


     $error = '';


   if(!$error)
     {
  $headers = 'From: your Website/email'."\r\n".
   'Reply-To: Email.@ste.com'."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
      if(@mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers))

  {

    echo 'OK';

    }



    }}
  ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. I can see where you are going with this, but $name = $row['firstname']; is not actually returning a value.

Comment: Do you have such column(firstname) in db? any Error?

Comment: Yes I have these rows in my database no errors though the mail gets sent but fills this space with "Array"

Comment: try passing id manually like SELECT * FROM tbl_client_info WHERE UCODE=somecode which exits in db.

Comment: uid is created when user logs in to site via index.php

Comment: try printing the uid, does it give any value?

Comment: You are a legend, I have not pulled the session over to this page so it has no idea which users details to send. Thank you so much for picking this up

Comment: Can you change your answer so that it relates to the :uid, I will then mark that. All working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the reply-to and from format doesnt look right. I would just create a variable for them and then stick it in the code.

```
$name = $row['firstname'];
$email = $row['billingemail'];
$subject = "myDraadloze Package Contact Card";
$message = stripslashes($_POST['Please contact user regarding example']);


$error = '';
$replyemail="'Reply-To: ".$name."<".$email.">'"."\r\n"; //looks likes this 'Reply-to: customer name <customeremail@whatever.com'\r\n
$fromemail="'from: ".$name."<".$email.">'"."\r\n"; //looks likes this 'from: customer name <customeremail@whatever.com'\r\n

//yours looked like this
//from:customername <customeremail@whatever.com\r\n
//these are headers and need to be seperated with '
//the ' should be at start and before \r\n

if(!$error)
{
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,$fromemail.$replyemail

    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```